# where to find step-by-step guide for smooth-looking + non-glitchy GIFs?

Tags: gif

It has been some time since I saw a sleek looking GIF like the one below. Usually, it'd be quite obvious if the GIF is looping but this is not the case, and it is quite high quality.

Any idea where I can learn step-by-step how to achieve this level of realism for a GIF?

[image]

Comment: I think there is not step by step guide how to become a good artist. You will find guides how to make gifs with AfterEffects and Photoshop. But to make your gif real looking like your example you just have to train.

Comment: i'm not asking about the artistic aspect of things, but the technical portion - how to achieve that level of realism through a GIF.

Comment: Create a video or series of images and convert them to GIF. You can use ffmpeg to do that: http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html or even online tool - https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif (it uses the same technique). Technically there is nothing special about this GIF. You shouldn't create your work directly in GIF format anyway.

Comment: Which part of this are you falling short of being able to accomplish yourself?

Comment: To achieve a seamless loop you need to learn how to loop first...there is no trick which will make it seamless instantly. For stuff like smoke and water its usually a lot overlaying footage.

Comment: There are limits to what Gif can do. There are color limits for example which look glitchy like the eyes in your frog. You can't do anything about that.

Comment: Not to sound blunt but it's the artistic aspect that makes this work. There's no technical fix for how to do it. Using technical knowledge, anyone can ensure the last few frames seamlessly match the first few. Making the animation subtly loop is down to artistic intuition and understanding the nuances of the rhythm in such a short scene and what aligns with patterns of movement in real life. Understanding a good compromise is an artistic skill.

Answer (score -1):

Making a seamless gif in a nutshell:

-Film: At least 1080p resolution.

-Edit:  Try and keep the length at a few seconds or under 10 as a best practice, keep the file size under 1MB to avoid uploading to social site issues, ensure lighting is the same in the   beginning and ending frames so the GIF doesn't appear to loop or restart.

-Use a GIF generator:  Giphy is a popular choice (https://giphy.com/create/gifmaker), add text, or download/share.

Check out this article, it has more in depth info https://idearocketanimation.com/14835-animated-gifs/

Here is an example of a seamless GIF from Giphy
[image]